# KNeighbors: ValueError 'continuous-multioutput'

Tags: python, pca, knn

> /home/dogus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:429:
>   **DataConversionWarning**: Data with input dtype int8 was converted to
>   float64 by the normalize function.   warnings.warn(msg,
>   _DataConversionWarning)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "assignment5.py", line 171,
>   in 
>       **knn.fit(X_train,y_train)**   File "/home/dogus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py",
>   line 775, in fit
>       check_classification_targets(y)   File "/home/dogus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py",
>   line 172, in check_classification_targets
>       raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
>   **ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'**

1-*What does 'continuous-multioutput' mean?*

2-*Is 'DataConversionWarning' something crucial?*

```
# TODO: Just like your preprocessing transformation, create a PCA
# transformation as well. Fit it against your training data, and then
# project your training and testing features into PCA space using the
# PCA model's .transform() method.
pca = PCA(n_components=2, svd_solver='auto')
pca.fit(X_train,y_train)

X_train = pca.transform(X_train)
y_train = pca.transform(y_train)
X_test = pca.transform(X_test) # should i transform tests?
y_test = pca.transform(y_test)

print X_train,"----",y_train
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=9)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Inputs:
  print X_train:
[[ 0.0669871   0.01377793]
 [-0.00501622 -0.06383211]
             ...
 [ 0.13320158  0.02851528]
 [-0.06106258 -0.02458237]]

print y_train:
[[ 0.02357345  0.01313697]
 [ 0.02357345  0.01313697]
          ...
 [ 0.02357345  0.01313697]
 [ 0.78585397  0.12070276]]

The main question is how can i solve this continuous-multioutput error?
Thank you.

Comment: You are using a classifier for regression, which is not possible. You target variable y has two dimensions (multioutput) and is not discrete (but continous). The real question is: What do you want to do? Classification or Regression? If you want to do classification please never PCA on your target variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but the instruction tells me to use pca before kneighbors.
https://github.com/authman/DAT210x/blob/master/Module5/assignment5.py
at 133th line
"""
# TODO: Create and train a KNeighborsClassifier. Start with K=9 neighbors.
# NOTE: Be sure train your classifier against the pre-processed, PCA-
# transformed training data above! You do not, of course, need to transform
# your labels."""

Comment: 1) Do not split test and traing data before PCA. 2) Perform PCA ONLY on X. 2a) pca.fit(X), 2b) pca.transform(X) 3) split test and train data 4) success.