# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput' when fitting data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to predict multiple outcomes based on one input parameter with `scikit-learn`'s `MultiOutputClassifier`.
For some reason I always get this error, and I do not know whats the problem:

`ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'`

I have tried to make `my_data['Clicked']` to be categorical data, I have tried this `my_data['Clicked'] = my_data['Clicked'].astype('category')`, but it gives me the same error.

I have tried the same code on some simple dummy database and it works perfectly.
This is the code that works:

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

dic = {'par_1': [10, 30, 13, 19, 25, 33, 23],
       'par_2': [1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2],
       'outcome': [101, 905, 182, 268, 646, 624, 465]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

variables = df.iloc[:,:-1]
results = df.iloc[:,-1]

multi_output_clf = MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs'))
multi_output_clf.fit(results.values.reshape(-1, 1),variables)

x = multi_output_clf.predict([[100]])
print(x)
```

For the code above, everything works, but for the code below, i get the error.
I do not know whats the problem because i have just used bigger data set and values based on which I predict the parameters are only 0's and 1's. Zeros and Ones should be classes(categories) like `yes` and `no` but if i change them to 'yes' and 'no'i get the error that `cannot convert string to float`.  Why this is not continuous 'outcome': [101, 905, 182, 268, 646, 624, 465] but series of 0's and 1's are continuous?

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

variables = my_data[['Clicked']] #values are integers, only 0 and 1 (0 = not clicked , 1 = clicked)
results = my_data[['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']] #values are integers and floats

multi_output_clf = MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs'))
multi_output_clf.fit(variables.values.reshape(-1, 1),results)

x = multi_output_clf.predict([1])
print(x)
```

Below is the part of full dataset that I have used (it gives me the same error):

```
dic = {'Daily Time on Site': [59.99, 88.91, 66.00, 74.53, 69.88, 47.64, 83.07, 69.57],
       'Age': [23,33,48,30,20,49,37,48],
       'Gender': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       'Clicked': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]}

my_data = pd.DataFrame(dic)

variables = my_data[['Clicked']] #values are only 0 and 1 (0 = not clicked , 1 = clicked)
results = my_data[['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']] #values are integers and floats

multi_output_clf = MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='ovr'))
multi_output_clf.fit(variables.values.reshape(-1, 1),results)

x = multi_output_clf.predict([1])
print(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211239/valueerror-unknown-label-type-continuous)

Comment: @DavidZemens I have checked that question and answer, but Its not the same, and it does not help. Its not the same error

Comment: The error appears to raise from the same problem, looking at that stack trace: `if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput', 'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']`. Clearly, `continuous-multioutuput` is not in that condition, and would raise the same error. So, have you tried regression? If so, show your work. part of asking a good Q is explaining what you've tried (and how those efforts may have failed).

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625077/kneighbors-valueerror-continuous-multioutput

Comment: I have read both of those answers before, but It does not answer my question. One of the answers is  'target variable y has two dimensions (multioutput) and is not discrete (but continous)'. How can I know If its discrete or continous?
Check out code that I wrote that works,  Why this is not continuous 'outcome': [101, 905, 182, 268, 646, 624, 465] but series of 0's and 1's are continuous?

Comment: Check updated question.

Comment: @taga, I had the same error. I think you might be overlooking the fact that somehow you have other than 0 or 1 in your dependent variable. Can you try `df.isFraud.value_counts()`? I found that I had 1 `0.5` somehow. No idea where it is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to go for `MultiOutputRegressor()`, as your output variables seems to be continuous.

Try the following change:

```
variables  = my_data[['Clicked']] #values are only 0 and 1 (0 = not clicked , 1 = clicked)
results = my_data[['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']] #values are integers and floats

multi_output_clf = MultiOutputRegressor(LinearRegression())
multi_output_clf.fit(variables.values.reshape(-1, 1),results)
```

**Update:**

```
>>> pd.cut(my_data['Daily Time on Site'],
...        3, labels=["low", "medium", "high"])

0       low
1      high
2    medium
3    medium
4    medium
5       low
6      high
7    medium
```

Note: It is not advisable to have integers as your categories, because number of categories might shoot really high when your variable has a huge range of values. Please bucket them into smaller groups say 10 or 20 and then consider them as categorical values.

Comment: I understand, but why? what does  continuous mean?
Why this is not continuous `'outcome': [101, 905, 182, 268, 646, 624, 465]  ` but series of 0's and 1's are continuous?

Comment: And I want to use classification

Comment: I have tried this `my_data['Clicked'] = my_data['Clicked'].astype('category') `  but it gives me the same error.

Comment: I have updated question, I have added one more part of code, so that you can test it

Comment: When I say output variables, I mean `['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']`. Continuous variable means the variables that cannt be coutable. refer [this](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/discrete-vs-continuous-variables/) link

Comment: So there is no way to change these variables `['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']` to be discreet?

Comment: @taga continuous variable mean a numerical variable. A continuous variable takes real values and these values can be infinite. Variable that cannot be counted are referred to as categorical. The categorical variable, in turn, can be either discrete or nominal

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, to eliminate this error, all values that are output variables, in this case `['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']` needs to be integers, not floats

```
dic = {'Daily Time on Site': [59.99, 88.91, 66.00, 74.53, 69.88, 47.64, 83.07, 69.57],
       'Age': [23,33,48,30,20,49,37,48],
       'Gender': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       'Clicked': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]}

my_data = pd.DataFrame(dic)
my_data['Daily Time on Site']= my_data['Daily Time on Site'].round(0)

variables = my_data[['Clicked']] #values are only 0 and 1 (0 = not clicked , 1 = clicked)
results = my_data[['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']] #values are integers and floats

multi_output_clf = MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='ovr'))
multi_output_clf.fit(variables.values.reshape(-1, 1),results)

x = multi_output_clf.predict([1])
print(x)
```

Comment: the number of categories in your `Daily Time on Site` can shoot really high, my suggestion would be to group them into some number of buckets based on your choice.

Comment: @taga, The answer that you posted works not because of float or real values but because of the choice of a classifier. You chose, `logistic regression` which by principle explains the relationship between one dependent binary variable and one or more nominal, ordinal, interval or ratio-level independent variables. Here the dependent binary variable is `Clicked`.

Comment: @ai_learning the variable `Daily Time on Site` in essence is a continuous variable. The suggestion of bucketing it, which in principle is akin to creating categories is somewhat dicey. because then the true nature of the variable will be lost. Another probelm that will arise is how to interpret and determine the precision of the resultant classier on the obfuscated buckets

Comment: Ok, so bottom line is...if im using `MultiOutputClassifier` my output values, in this case `['Daily Time on Site', 'Age', 'Gender']` should be "classes"/"categories" ?